# Clarification on the big oh of the sum of two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computational-complexity

In computing the asymptotic complexity of the sum of two functions, one theorem states that if $\large\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_2(n)}{f_1(n)}$ exists, then the asymptotic complexity is $f_1(n)$. The author gave an example of adding $f_1(n)=n^3$ and $f_2(n)=n^2$. He determined that the limit exists and concluded that the complexity was $O(f_1(n))$ or $O(n^3)$.

Obviously the value of the functions matter because if we switched it around and made $f_1(n)=n^2$ and $f_2(n)=n^3$, then we couldn't compute the complexity that way as $\large\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^3}{n^2} = \infty$ which does not exist.

Is this correct? If so, how do I make sure I am adding the right way?

Comment: $f_1$ must be the "greater" function. If you can't decide which one it is, try both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, but I think it's the phrasing that's confused, order doesn't matter here in quite the way you seem to think it does. (If I'm interpreting your statement correctly.) Carefully phrased, you've found:

Because $$\lim \frac{n^2}{n^3} = 0$$ we can say that $n^2$ is $O(n^3)$ (it's also $O(n^2)$). Because $$\lim\frac{n^3}{n^2} =\infty$$ we can say that $n^3$ is not $O(n^2)$.

I think maybe the example you were looking for is:

Since $$\lim\frac{n^3+n^2}{n^3} =1$$ we know that $n^3 +n^2 = n^2 +n^3$ is $O(n^3)$.

A major use of this (in a slightly different context $x\to 0$) is to make statements of the form: $$e^x = 1 + x + O(x^2)$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: As stated by Exodd, it's really a question of which function grows fastest.

Comment: Where you say $e^x = 1 + x + O(x^2)$, I believe you mean as $x\to 0$. Hence, that example may invite confusion since in the OP's question (and I would say, most of the time when people first learn about Big-Oh notation) we're dealing with limits of the form $n \to \infty$.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics

Comment: @mathmandan, good catch. I edited to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This all derives from the fact that if $f_2 \subset f_1$, i.e. function of a lower order, we can always find some $n_0 >n$ and constant $a$ s.t. $f_1 + f_2 < f_1 +a f_1 = (1+a)f_1 = O(f_1)$